# Draw a tracer line between mouse pointer and a point of a line

Tags: c#, graphics, line, point

I have a kinda CAD application. I have class of line.

> ```
> public class Line
> {
>     public float width { get; set; }
>     public bool selected { get; set; }
>     public Color color { get; set; }
>     public Point Start { get; set; }
>     public Point End { get; set; }
>
>     public Line(Color col, float w, Point s, Point e)
>     {
>
>         color = col;
>         Start = s;
>         End = e;
>         width = w;
>
>     }
>     public void Draw(Graphics G)
>     {
>         using (Pen pen = new Pen(color, width))
>         {
>             G.DrawLine(pen, Start, End);
>         }
>     }
> ```
>
> I have a list named Lines. 
>   The lines are drawn on a panel

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics grp = e.Graphics;
foreach (Line L in Lines.Except(DelLines))
            {
                L.Draw(grp);
            }
 if (mouseisdown && Line == true)
            {

                grp.DrawLine(Pens.White, DsP1, new Point(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y - 158));
                //     double d = Math.Abs((DsP1.X - MousePosition.X) + (DsP1.Y - (MousePosition.Y - 158)));
                if (snapON == true)
                {
                    grp.DrawLine(Pens.Yellow, snapPoint, mousePoint);

                }
           }
```

Here mousePoint is Point(mouseposition.X,mouseposition.Y-158).
158 is because my panel is located 158 Y below the top of window.
Then i have a mouseUp Event

> ```
>    private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
>     {
>         mouseisdown = false;
>         if (Line == true)
>         {
>
>             PointsList.Add(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
>             Lines.Add(new PolygonArea.Line(Color.White, 1, DsP1, new Point(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y - 158)));
>             Line = false;
>
>         } }
> ```

Now i want to draw a line on mouse move which will tell to mouse position its x axis or y axis is matching a point of a line in lines list. What i tried is:

in Panel1_MouseMove Event

> ```
>  if(Line==true && Lines.Count>1)
>         {
>                                 if (Lines[0].Start.X == e.Location.X || 
> Lines[0].Start.Y==e.Location.Y)
>                 {
>                 snapON = true;
>                     snapPoint = Lines[0].Start;
>                 panel1.Invalidate();
>                 }
>                 else if(Lines[0].End.X==e.Location.X || Lines[0].End.Y == e.Location.Y)
>                 {
>                 snapON = true;
>                     snapPoint = Lines[0].End;
>                 panel1.Invalidate();
>                 }
>             }
> ```

Just for the test, i refer to first line in lines which is Lines[0]. But i cant get a line drawn between mousepointer and line's point when condition met. 
Any idea??

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Just had to add SnapON=false after line is drawn in Paint Event. And I have to remove panel1.invalidate from mouse_move event... 
Thanks guys